# Doing things with images

Tags: javascript, input, camera

I have the following input

```
<input class="text-right" type="file" id="cameraupload" name="upload" accept="image/*"/></input>
```

How can I use jQuery (or javascript if necessary) to get what was uploaded and put it on the page in a div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <input type='file' id="imgInp" />
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
</form>

<script>
    function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#blah').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to put the image into #blah